# How to add text to a readonly input display for a calculator project?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to add numbers to the display area of my html/css calculator on the click of a button but it does not work.
`




C
7
8
9
/
4
5
6
*
1
2
3
-
0
.
=
+




const display = document.getElementById("display");

```
function appendToDisplay(val) {
    display.value = display.value + val;
}

function clearDisplay () {
    display.value = "";
}
```

`

I tried using a innerHTML property instead of value property on the display variable.

Comment: Can you provide also your **html** code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

based on my understanding, hope this helps! Good luck with your calculator project.

```js
function clf(a) {
    var b = display.value;
    display.value = b + a

    if (a === "clearone") {
        display.value = b.slice(0, -1);
    } else if (a === "clearall") {
        display.value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="display" type="text" readonly>

<button onclick="clf('1')">1</button>
<button onclick="clf('2')">2</button>
<button onclick="clf('3')">3</button>
<button onclick="clf('4')">4</button>
<button onclick="clf('5')">5</button>
<button onclick="clf('6')">6</button>
<button onclick="clf('7')">7</button>
<button onclick="clf('8')">8</button>
<button onclick="clf('9')">9</button>
<button onclick="clf('0')">0</button>

<button onclick="clf('clearall')">Clear All</button>
<button onclick="clf('clearone')">Clear One</button>
```